# repetition detection in O(Log n) in sorted array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, array-algorithms

Given a sorted integer array A of size n, where n is a multiple of 4. Could someone help me how to find an algorithm that decides whether not there exists an element that repeats at least n/4 times in the array in O(log n) time.

Comment: That's an interesting problem, but the question is in a form which is highly discouraged here.

Comment: That means that there are at least `n/4` consecutive occurrences. Just consider the 4 `n/4` subarrays take the middle element and search the first and last occurrences using bisection and check their distance. It works because that element either occur in the middle of subarray `x:x+n/4` or it occurrs in the middle of the previus or next block.   In fact this works for any array size, the difference is that when `n` is not a multiple of `4` you have to repeat this a 5th time (still O(log n) though).

Comment: In fact you don't even have to take the middle element. The first one works to. just choose any relative index in the subarray and check for this on all subarrays. If it isn't the repeating one it means that the first element of the next or prio subarray must be it (if there is one).

Answer (score 2):

If there is an element that repeats n/4 times, it must also occupy one of the following indices: `n/4, 2n/4, 3n/4, n`.

For each of these elements, do two binary searches to find the first index it occupies and the last one.

This totals in 4*2 binary searches, each taking `O(logn)` time. This gives you total run time of `O(8*logn) = O(logn)`